# Regex help with matching

Tags: regex, perl

Hello I need coming up with a valid regular expression It could be any identifier name that starts with a letter or underscore but may contain any number of letters, underscores, and/or digits (all letters may be upper or lower case).
For example, your regular expression should match the following text strings:  “_”, “x2”, and “This_is_valid”  It should not match these text strings: “2days”, or “invalid_variable%”.

So far this is what I have came up with but I don't think it is right

```
/^[_\w][^\W]+/
```

Comment: A letter is `\pL`.  A digit is `\d`.  But an alphabetic is `\p{Alphabetic}`. That should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work:

```
/^[_a-zA-Z]\w*$/
```

Starts with (`^`) a letter (upper or lowercase) or underscore (`[_a-zA-Z]`), followed by any amount of letter, digit, or underscore (`\w`) to the end (`$`)

Read more about [Regular Expressions in Perl](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the below regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z_]\w*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If the identify is at the start of a string, then it's easy

`/^(_|[a-zA-Z]).*/`

If it's embedded in a longer string, I guess it's not much worse, assuming it's the start of a word...

`/\s(_|[a-zA-Z]).*/`

Comment: `.*` is going to match stuff you don't want. `%`, `$`, `#` etc.